# Is there a way to protect / unprotect a word in Red like in Rebol?

Tags: rebol, red

Protect/Unprotect exist in Rebol, they don't seem to exist in Red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not implemented yet, that should happen in 0.8.0, with the introduction of modules.